# What's the best place for resources for [navigation] wpf pages?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm using a frame in a usercontrol that is in a window.  The frame is used to host pages that I navigate through.  I have a set of common styles that I'd like to place in one place outside of the pages.  I'm not sure what the best place would be.  I tried the window and the usercontrol (i.e. Window.Resources and UserControl.Resources in the corresponding places) but the styles could not be seen in the pages.  They do work fine in each page placed in Page.Resources.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to move your resources in `App.xaml`. [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746624.aspx).

Comment: I tried to move styles to App.xaml but with no success.  Btw, my pages (xaml files) are in ./views/ folder while app.xaml is in a folder one level up (i.e. app root folder: ./). Would that make a difference?

Comment: I think it should not. `App.xaml` file is *global*, and all the styles that are there, the project should see. But in this situation, is 100 percent can not be sure.